# Intercept all HTTP requests going out of a Java Application

Tags: java, spring, rest, http-headers

In our project, we need to pass a certain header information in all the REST calls that are sent out to other internal APIs.

One way is to change all the hundreds or even thousands of REST invocations to add this mapping before the REST call is initiated.

But, I was wondering if there is a smarter way of doing this using aspects/filters/listeners/interceptors in Spring/Java?

Example: If I make a call from REST API 1 to an endpoint, I am trying to explore a way to intercept the constructed HTTP request and add the header and fire the request.

Any suggestions about solving or any other good practices are welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are using the Spring RestTemplate then the ClientHttpRequestInterceptor might be what you are looking for

Comment: Most Frameworks that send HTTP Requests have some build in functionality to configure the Headers, so you do not need AOP. But this depends strongly on the HTTP/Rest Framework you use. -- so tell us which framework do you use, an example how you use it would also be helpful to write an good answer that helps you.

Comment: Maybe you should clarify wich REST client library you're using. ¿Spring RestTemplate? Then follow Nitek's advice.

Comment: Sorry about the delay to respond and thank you all for the answers. Yes it is Spring RestTemplate and my implementation coincided with what Nitek suggested here. I did implement the ClientHttpRequestInterceptor and set it to the restTemplate in the postConstruct of a bean I have used it and seemed to work fine. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 7):

For any person who stumbles upon this post in the future, here is what it took to make it working.

Implement a class that 'implements' ClientHttpRequestInterceptor. The method that needs to be overridden is where you can catch the request headers and modify them.

Comment: And here's a good blog post on the topic: http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/27/how-to-send-an-http-header-with-every-request-with-spring-resttemplate